# C# three bools one true at a time

Tags: c#, boolean

I have three booleans in c#. Each allows for a different menu to be open. However, only one can be true at any given time. So if i press a button and that button turns the corresponding boolean true to the corresponding menu, but I want a slick check that turns the others false if they are true before turning that boolean true. Not sure if this is making much sense. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, web?

Comment: A slick check??? Just check your bools and be done with it.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505)

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you want *one* variable, possibly using an enum:

```
public enum ActiveMenu
{
    None,
    Settings,
    MainMenu,
    OtherMenu
}
```

Then have a variable of type `ActiveMenu`, which will obviously only be able to hold a single value at a time. That feels like a more sensible approach than having three separate (but inextricably entwined) Boolean variables.

Answer (score 4):

Turn all three booleans false, then turn the one true that you want.